# Program that reads a picture and extracts the words in the picture?

Tags: extract, pictures

Not sure if this is the appropriate subboard for this question.
What I'm trying to do is essentially:
(1) I'm given a picture of a book/paper. All the words in this picture were typed, but I cannot extract the words with my cursor. 
(2) From this picture, I want to extract all the words. Is there a program that can take in the picture and extract all the words (with spaces, caps, punctuation, etc...)?

Comment: Try searching on [softwarerecs.se]. I suspect this would already have an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing [Optical Character Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) (OCR), and [Google Drive can do this](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) by uploading your images and converting them to google Docs

[image]

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions, it only encourages the OP.

Comment: @davidpostill It was tagged off topic while or AFTER I answered.

Comment: *shrug* with your rep you should know *before* you answer what is on topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill  That doesn't make any sense, for someone who has nearly six figures of rep I'd thought you'd be discernible.